# How can I perform an order-independent equality check on lists?

Tags: java, list, optimization, equals

I want to implement an equals method on a class where the equality of instances is derived from the 'weak' equality of the contained lists, i. e. the same order of the list elements is not necessary, whereas `java.util.List.equals(Object)` (you can see its javadoc below) demands the same order.

So, what's the best way to perform an order-independent equality check on lists?

---

I thought of wrapping the lists into new lists, sorting them and then performing the equals there on.

Or another approach (that would make this question obsolete): Use a TreeSet instead, this way the order of the elements would always be the same in sets with equal elements.

```
/**
 * Compares the specified object with this list for equality.  Returns
 * <tt>true</tt> if and only if the specified object is also a list, both
 * lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
 * the two lists are <i>equal</i>.  (Two elements <tt>e1</tt> and
 * <tt>e2</tt> are <i>equal</i> if <tt>(e1==null ? e2==null :
 * e1.equals(e2))</tt>.)  In other words, two lists are defined to be
 * equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.  This
 * definition ensures that the equals method works properly across
 * different implementations of the <tt>List</tt> interface.
 *
 * @param o the object to be compared for equality with this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the specified object is equal to this list
 */
boolean equals(Object o);
```

---

I know the answer and closed the tab. Afterwards I read a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82276/is-it-good-to-ask-a-question-whose-answer-you-already-know-and-not-to-auto-an) on meta about what to do in these kind of situations. But since my question was cached by SO, I'm going to post it anyway. Maybe someone has the same 'problem' in future. I'm going to post the answer, if no one does.

Comment: Use a `Set<YourClass>` backed by `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`, note that `TreeSet` uses `compareTo` method instead of `equals`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Creating a Set will remove duplicates. So, 2 equal Sets don't confirm that the Lists are also equal.

Comment: @RohitJain if there are duplicated elements in first list then there's no need to compare them against the elements in the second list since they would already be compared by the first appearance of them in first list.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. I mean to say - `[1, 1, 2]` is not equal to `[1, 2]`. But creating a set out of them will make the sets equal.

Comment: @RohitJain then use a `Map<YourClass, Integer>` where the key is the element in the list and the value is a counter of that element in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can convert both Lists to Bags and just use equals() between the Bags. The contract of `Bag.equals()` is that two Bags are equal if they have the same number of each element, but order doesn't factor in. There's a performance benefit too. `toBag()` and `Bag.equals()` are each O(n), so this method is faster than sorting the Lists.

```
Assert.assertEquals(
    Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 1).toBag(),
    Lists.mutable.with(3, 2, 1, 1).toBag());
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 6):

If you have no objections against adding 3rd party libraries, you can use `CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)` from Apache Commons-Lang. It essentially compares two arbitrary collection (also Lists), ignoring the order of the elements.

From the API documentation:

> Returns true iff the given Collections contain exactly the same
>   elements with exactly the same cardinalities. That is, iff the
>   cardinality of e in a is equal to the cardinality of e in b, for each
>   element e in a or b.

Comment: Note that this compares using the cardinality of the elements in both lists, OP wants/needs an algorithm that compares the lists using order independent equality.

Comment: @Luiggi: And the difference is?

Comment: You're both right. I said order independant. But that indeed doesn't exclude cardinality. Interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several ways to do this, including iterating over a list and using `list.contains` as Sotirios mentions in his comment.  Another would be to use `(new HashSet(list1)).equals(new HashSet(list2))`(Both of these solutions would discard duplicate entries however).

Another way that would include testing for the equivalence of duplicate entries would be to use `Collections.sort()` to make sorted copies of both lists and then `.equals()` to compare that way.  There's a variety of sound ways to do this, probably many more than I've mentioned here.

Comment: My solution was no good. What if you have the same element twice in one list but only once in the other? Are they still considered equal?

Comment: I might add that if you don't particularly care about the order of the elements in your list you might be better off using a Set anyway

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hmm good point...  in that case `Collections.sort()` would probably be the best way to do it.  You could sort a copy of the Lists and compare the copies so you don't affect the original order

Comment: @StormeHawke: No, a Set is not simply an unordered List. You can only use Collections.sort() if the elements in the List implement Comparable.

Comment: @Jarnbjo I know that.  I hadn't considered the possibility of duplicate entries

Comment: Also, `Collections.sort()` was intended as a separate way of solving the problem, not to be mixed in with the `HashSet` implementation

Answer (score 1):

Since there are already some answers. I'm going to post mine.

I finally used `java.util.List.containsAll(Collection<?>)`. Me stumbling over this method was the reason I didn't want to post the question.

@jarnbjo Did not realize that there is also the dimension of cardinality you can consider!

**EDIT**

Added sth. to fix the cardinality problem.

```
  Collection<Object> a, b;

  boolean equal = (a.size() == b.size()) && a.containsAll(b);
```

But this could fail, too. If collection a has item x twice, and collection b has item y twice. Then the size is the same and `containsAll()` yields `true`.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think this solution would be able to detect whether there is more than one of the same element in a List.  I'd have to test but I think [1,1,2].containsAll([1,2]) would return true (pseudocode)

Comment: Of course if you don't care about that, then my comment is moot :)

Comment: I assumed that since you asked for the behaviour of List.equals without the requirement of both lists having the same order, that you in case of duplicates require duplicates to occur in the same number in both list. E.g. [1, 1, 2] is equal to [1, 2, 1] but not equal to [1, 2, 2]. Your solution with `containsAll` would not fulfill such a requirement.

Comment: Moreover, it has a quadratic complexity as it looks for each element of the first list in the second. I'd either sort the lists (assuming the items are `Comparable`) or use Guava's `Multiset`.